# how to take only times from dates inside array in rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

so... i need to take times from dates inside Array

so for example I have an array like this

```
    a = [
     Thu, 17 Mar 2022 10:00:00.000000000 KST +09:00,
     Thu, 17 Mar 2022 10:00:00.000000000 KST +09:00,
     Thu, 17 Mar 2022 14:00:00.000000000 KST +09:00,
     Thu, 17 Mar 2022 14:00:00.000000000 KST +09:00,
     Thu, 17 Mar 2022 17:00:00.000000000 KST +09:00]
```

and wanted to have result of

```
a = ["10:00", "10:00", "14:00", "14:00", "17:00"]
```

So i was trying this

```
can_choose =[];

a.each_with_index do |time| strftime("%H:%M")
can_choose <<|time|
```

but doesn't works at all...

where should I have to fix??

Comment: I guess that `a` is an Array of strings, but to clarify this, maybe it is better to write the assignment to `a` in your post as a syntactically valid Ruby statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also extract the year, month, day the same way
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html

```
a = [
'Thu, 17 Mar 2022 10:00:00.000000000 KST +09:00',
'Thu, 17 Mar 2022 10:00:00.000000000 KST +09:00',
'Thu, 17 Mar 2022 14:00:00.000000000 KST +09:00',
'Thu, 17 Mar 2022 14:00:00.000000000 KST +09:00',
'Thu, 17 Mar 2022 17:00:00.000000000 KST +09:00']


can_choose =[]
a.map do |time|
 t = DateTime.parse(time)
 can_choose << t.strftime("%k:%M")
end 

p can_choose

=> ["10:00", "10:00", "14:00", "14:00", "17:00"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is all about message passing. The syntax to send a message is:

```
receiver.message(argument)
```

`strftime` is such message, but it needs a proper *receiver*. So if you have some `Time` instance, e.g.:

```
time = Time.parse('2022-03-17 10:00:00 +0900')
```

you'd write:

```
time.strftime('%H:%M') #=> "10:00"
```

with `time` being the receiver, `strftime` being the message and `'%H:%M'` being the argument.

You can use the above code in an `each` loop like this:

```
can_choose = []

a.each do |time|
  can_choose << time.strftime('%H:%M')
end
```

Or you could use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Array.html#map-method) to convert your array to another array:

```
can_choose = a.map { |time| time.strftime('%H:%M') }
```

The curly braces here `{ ... }` are equivalent to the `do ... end` block above.

Answer (score 2):

I would simple go with:

```
can_choose = a.map { |datetime| datetime.strftime('%H:%M') }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need only hours and minutes in 24h format, just use `%R` directive with [`Time#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#method-i-strftime) or [`DateTime#strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime)

```
can_choose = a.map { |time| time.strftime('%R') }
```